# Download bitnami magento 2.1?

Tags: magento, download, bitnami

Can anyone tell me a website where I could download Bitnami Magento version 2.1 Installer for Windows?
I checked in the Bitnami website and it´s only the 2.2 version

Comment: You can get a Docker image of this from here: https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-magento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check all Bitnami versions in the changelog of the Bitnami Application, in this case, for Magento you can take a look to https://bitnami.com/stack/magento/changelog.txt.

Regarding the installer, you can download it following this link:

https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacks/magento/2.1.9-0/bitnami-magento-2.1.9-0-windows-installer.exe

`md5:1b63a954add3e8678906b917f6876230`